# Swift 3. Trying to update from viewController some IBOutlets declared in prototype cell class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I have cells in a tableView with 2 labels displaying text.
Cells are managed in a detailCell class of type `UITableViewCell`, that references IBOutlets for both labels. This allows me to manage my prototype cell and display core data entries.

I added `UITextField` (with border style invisible) on top of each label and I would like to hide the label when user taps the textField and starts editing.

Problem is I cannot figure how to manage the label (referenced in the prototype class) from my viewController without referencing a second time the label in the viewController. Of course this fires the error: "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content".

The other way round would be to hide/display label by managing it from the cell class, according to the `var isEditing: Bool` that I use in the viewController, but I do not manage to use it in the cell class.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should configure the cell according to the editing state in `cellForRowAt` and reload the visible cells when the editing mode changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to do something like below:

-> First of all you have to set all of your text fields delegate to self

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let aCell : myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aCell") as! myCustomCell

        aCell.txtView1.delegate = self
    return aCell    
    }
```

-> Secondly you have to get particular cell when user click on textfiels

```
     func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

          //Get parent cell by traveling to the superview as your cell (Depends on your view hierarchy in your cell)
            let aCell : myCustomCell = textField.superview?.superview as! myCustomCell

//Hide below label
aCell.lblData.hidden = true

        }
```

--> Third, you have to hide text field and show label again when text field end editing get called

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let aCell : myCustomCell = textField.superview?.superview as! myCustomCell

    //Hide below label
    aCell.lblData.text = textField.text
    aCell.lblData.hidden = false
    }
```

Comment: -> First point: 
by 'textView1' do you mean the name of my textField (IBOutlet) that is referenced in my class myCustomCell (in a separate file)?
Here I have the error "cannot assign value of type myCustomCell to type UITextFieldDelegate?".

-> Second & Third points:
I added those functions to my class file.
Where shall I add them in the viewController?

Comment: -> First point: Yes, 'textView1' is your (IBOutlet)  that is referenced in your class myCustomCell (in a separate file).

->Second:  You have to add those text field delegate functions in your viewController class because we added all those text field's delegate to self (have a look in 'cellForRow' method).

Comment: The logic behind the code is when user will tap on particular cell's text field we will get call back in 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' method because we did it's delegate to self in 'cellForRow' method so in that method we will get its parent cell and hide label which is behind it.

After that when user will end editing we will get call back in 'textFieldDidEndEditing' method so we set label's text from textField.text and unhide label.

Comment: Thank you Govind. Actually I couldn't figure out how to use textField.superview?.superview without having a cast error. So based on your answer I used the workaround : (1) I created a global variable isEditing: Bool. (2) I did the IBOutlet view management in my class file. (3) I added TAG in interface builder for my two textFields. (4) In textFieldEndEditing() I used for both text fields : let textField1 = textField.viewWithTag(myTag) as! UITextField. (5) Finally I catch out the text with textField1.text.